# DefaultHandler & Quotes

Tags: android, xml

I have made a class XmlHandler that extends DefaultHandler and reads XML. The XML contains the following tag.

> `<description>"like" us on facebook</description>`

Without quotes its easy to grab the value using the `characters` method and put it in an object.  With quotes surrounding `like` however I'm having a problem.  The `characters` method does not receive the full `description` with one call, but `characters` is called 4 times, each time receiving only part of the description.

Is there a way to format the xml, so it can be read correctly by DefaultHandler or do I have to add some logic to account for the existence of quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  I was checking the XML in Chrome & IE and it looked correct, but viewing the source I found the PHP XMLWriter class I was using to create the XML was changing the character **"** to **&quot;**.  DefaultHandler doesn't seem to like this...

I had to stop using XMLWriter() and create my own writer to output a **"** actually as **"** so the DefaultHandler can translate it correctly.